# What could have cause my .git directory to completely disappear?

Tags: git, repository

Somehow the `.git` directory in my favorite local repository disappeared overnight. Everything else in the folder is intact. I'm running `Linux Mint` and the `history` command tells me that the last thing I did last night was add some files to the project after which I did a `git commit -a`.

Then I went to sleep and when I woke up and tried to add another file the `.git` directory was completely gone, as I soon discovered when git informed me that the folder in question was not a `git` repository.

There's no damage done because all the other files in the project folder are still there and the program itself runs, so that's not a big deal. The project is also on GitHub so I can retrieve all the previous commits if I feel like it, I guess.

My question is what could have caused this? (I'm asking so maybe I'll find some way to help prevent this from happening in the future.)

Comment: Did you check/enable the hidden files and folders? In many companies the hidden files if shown are hid again automatically.

Comment: @vijayinani it can't be that. `.`, `..` and 2 of my own invisible folders are showing up. In fact one of them, named `.backup`, has a `.git` directory inside of it for some crazy reason I don't even know about because I didn't put it there. Not something to complain about but it's a couple of days old. I'm really just learning `git` and have no idea what will happen if I break that folder out of `.backup` and do a commit. Think that'd fix it?